# Draw/create vector images from app

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I need users to be able to draw and type on a vector image. The user shall also be able to resize and move paths/texts so the "elements" needs to be able to receive click/touch events.

The problem is that I don't know how I should draw them on screen to be able to handle the events and save the result. Canvas doesn't seem to let me do that.

Anyone that can lead me to the right track?

The only thing I can think of is a WebView and develop the hole thing using JS and SVG. But that doesn't feel right...

I will use a API level of at least 11 but up to 13 is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one big [AndroidGraphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) stretched on the screen and catch all the touchDown Events, which give you coordinates and decide for yourself what to do with them.

Try [libGdx framework](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) which has already implemented most details for you (plus it runs GL Es)